# How to add seam in existing JSF application?

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam, liferay

I have existing JSF portlet application running in Liferay ,How to add Seam support? I am using JSF2. Also I am confused which seam version should I use? Seam2 or Seam3?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

I've not added Seam support to an existing JSF application, so I can't comment on that part. If you are using JSF2, though, your only option at this point is Seam 3. Support for JSF2 is slated for Seam 2.3, but that is in Beta right now. Here's the latest info I've seen on Seam 2.3: https://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2012/04/02/seam-230beta1-is-out

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah. I am interested in Seam 3 http://seamframework.org/Seam3 .I am not familiar with seam, and looks like there is a lot of difference between seam 2 and seam 3

Comment: Yes, Seam 2 and 3 are very different from each other. If you aren't familiar with Seam 3, then you might just want to start off with standard Java EE 6 until you run into a situation that could be helped by Seam 3. Much of the functionality Seam 2 added to Java EE 5 and JSF 1.2 has been added to Java EE 6 and JSF 2. Seam 2 was a framework, Seam 3 is more like a set of useful add-ons.